# Wordpress: How to allow some comment-actions (delete, edit...) only to specific roles?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook, wordpress-admin, wordpress-roles

Is it possible to customize Wordpress via action, hook or anything, that

1. only users of role "administrator" or "editor" may trash, spam or edit comments from the backend?
2. only users of role "administrator" or "editor" may trash, spam or edit comments from mail that will be generated on new comments?

I did not find anything on codex.wordpress.org as well as I did not find a proper plugin. :-/

Thanks!

Comment: You can use plugins like [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) or [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/)

Comment: Hi @Jainil, sure you might use a plugin that manages roles, rights, pages etc. IMHO thats like using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut. I hoped for a lighter, less intrusive approach, which I found in `$wp_roles->remove_cap($rolename, 'moderate_comments');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice using a plugin such as [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) for this, but hey - heres a working code example :):

In the the class `WP_Role` you'll find a property named ‘edit_comment’ which is mapped to the ‘edit_posts’ thus isn't handled as a separate capability. we can however modify the behaviour by applying a filter to the selected user role we want to restrict editing comments on by using the [map_meta_cap](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/) function.

**Example for:**
*Only users "administrator" or "editor" may trash, spam or edit comments from the backend:*

```
<?php
// Restrict editing capability of comments using `map_meta_cap`
function restrict_comment_editing( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
 if ( 'edit_comment' == $cap ) {
      // Allowed roles 
      $allowed_roles = ['editor', 'administrator'];

      // Checks for multiple users roles
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      $is_allowed = array_diff($allowed_roles, (array)$user->roles);

      // Remove editing capabilities on the back-end if the role isn't allowed
      if(count($allowed_roles) == count($is_allowed))
        $caps[] = 'moderate_comments';
      }
  }

  return $caps;
}

add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'restrict_comment_editing', 10, 4 );

// Hide comment editing options on the back-end*
add_action('init', function() {
  // Allowed roles
  $allowed_roles = ['editor', 'administrator'];

  // Checks for multiple users roles
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $is_allowed = array_diff($allowed_roles, (array)$user->roles);

  if(count($allowed_roles) == count($is_allowed)) {
    add_filter('bulk_actions-edit-comments', 'remove_bulk_comments_actions');
    add_filter('comment_row_actions', 'remove_comment_row_actions');
  }
});

function remove_bulk_comments_actions($actions) {
  unset($actions['unapprove']);
  unset($actions['approve']);
  unset($actions['spam']);
  unset($actions['trash']);

  return $actions;
}

function remove_comment_row_actions($actions) {
  unset($actions['approve']);
  unset($actions['unapprove']);
  unset($actions['quickedit']);
  unset($actions['edit']);
  unset($actions['spam']);
  unset($actions['trash']);

  return $actions;
}
?>
```

Code goes into your **functions.php** file

Comment: Cool, thanks for the code, this is great for the dashboard. It does not affect the email but gives me a starting point.
I like this approach much more than 'user role editor', 'advanced-access-manager' and other role-plugins, because they do much more than I need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kradyy I came around to [map_meta_cap](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/) and [remove_cap](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap).

With the following in the **functions.php**, the links are removed in the comments section of the dashboard as well as in the email sent to the author (except for admins and editors):

```
global $wp_roles;
$allowed_roles = ['editor', 'administrator'];
foreach (array_keys($wp_roles->roles) as $role){
    if (!in_array($role, $allowed_roles)) {
        $wp_roles->remove_cap( $role, 'moderate_comments' );
    }
}
```